# Get selected option even if it hasn't changed

Tags: jquery, onchange, html-select

jquery's `.change` event can be used to get the selected value in a `select` when a new option is selected:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var selectedValue = $('option:selected').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

How can I get the value if the selected option hasn't changed?

> i.e 'Option 1' is selected. User then selects 'Option 1' again. I need
>   to get the value at this point.

`.onchange` doesn't fire under these circumstances.

Is there another event that can be used?

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/)

Comment: Can't you just read the value as needed? - Why do you need it bound to an event?

Comment: It's a navigation menu on mobile. I need the value when the user selects a menu item

Comment: use the click event instead

Answer (score 1):

try this .. 
first alert will give unchanged value.

```
var defaultVal = $('select').val();
alert(defaultVal);
$('select').change(function() {
   var selectedValue = $(this).val();
alert(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: Try selecting the already selected option http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/7/ Doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

You can use click even on options I don't know if it works on all the browsers
check out the documentation 
[here](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp), this way you can get any click event on options

Comment: Already tried that. `.click` doesn't work on options. In chrome atleast. http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/6/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.selected = function(fn) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var clicknum = 0;
            $(this).click(function() {
                clicknum++;
                if (clicknum == 2) {
                    clicknum = 0;
                    fn(this);
                }
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$('select').selected(function(val) {
    alert(val.value)
});
```

**DEMO** `-- >` http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/5/

Comment: Your demo doesn't work for me in chrome. Nothing is alerted no matter what is selected?

Comment: @3rror404  Works fine for me.. :)

Answer (score 0):

try this. passed test on IE11 and FireFox 35.01.
this one avoid the bug, in Dhaval Marthak's code example, which will call the function on the second click, no matter if you clicked on the option.

more:
http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/11/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.selected = function(fn) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $select = $(this);
            var val = $select.val();
            $(this).children('option').on('click',function() {
                if(val === $(this).val()){
                    $select.trigger('unchange');
                }else{
                    // $select.trigger('change');
                }
                fn(this);
                val = $select.val();
            });
        });
    }
})(jQuery);

$('select').selected(function(val) {
    alert(val.value)
}).on('unchange',function(){
    alert('unchange');
}).on('change',function(){
    alert('change');
});
```

to support chrome(version 40.0.2214.115m), Firfox 35.01, IE 11:
http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/13/

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.selected = function(fn) {
        return this.each(function() {
            var $select = $(this);
            var val = $select.val();
            var optionClick = false;
           $(this).children('option').each(function(i,e){
                $(this).get(0).onclick = function() {
                    optionClick=true;
                    if(val === $(this).val()){
                        $select.trigger('unchange');
                    }else{
                        // $select.trigger('change');
                    }
                    fn(this);
                    val = $select.val();
                }
            });

            var clicked = 0, changed = 0;
            $select.on('change',function(){
                changed++;
            }).on('click',function(ev){
                if(true === optionClick){
                    /*do nothing*/                  
                }else{
                    if(0 === changed && 0 > ev.offsetX && 0 > ev.offsetY){
                        $select.trigger('unchange');
                            fn(this);
                    }else{             
                        changed = 0;
                    }
                }
            });
        });

    }
})(jQuery);

$('select').selected(function(val) {
    console.log(val.value)
}).on('click',function(ev){
     //console.log(ev);
}).on('unchange',function(){
    console.log('unchange');
}).on('change',function(){
    console.log('change');
});
```

Comment: thanks for mention. I did some upgrade for chrome (do not have safari currenly), and my firefox is 35.01(which do work for the first/second solution). now see :http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/13/

Comment: @uʍopǝpısdn . After trying to identify it as reasonable as i can, I guess that without using browser detect plugin or self rendered UI(e.g.https://github.com/jquery-collection/jQuery-Skinner). we can't code compatibly for all  browser. Also, I hacked a solution to support safari in Windows7, which I do NOT suggested(http://jsfiddle.net/cR3MQ/14/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.yourSelect option').click(function() {
    var selectedValue = $('.yourSelect').val();
    console.log(selectedValue);
});
```

Comment: It's best to add some sort of explanation to your answers so the poster knows why it might work.